# Citation of a book chapter that was put online

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am trying to cite, using the ACS format, https://www.intechopen.com/books/cancer-causing-substances/heavy-metals-and-cancer, but I don't know whether it is considered a book or ebook chapter. How am I supposed to tell them apart? The link is under "books" on the website, but seeing as it is online, wouldn't it be considered an ebook? If I cite it as a book, it'll be pretty weird for me to include a link and the date accessed, won't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would cite this as a book section, including the DOI (because that's where you found it/how others will be able to find it) but *not* including "date accessed", because that is intended for more volatile resources like web pages. (If a reference has a DOI you can usually treat it as non-volatile.)

Sticking as precisely as you can to a reference format is important, but the most important thing is to make sure that the information is present that allows readers to (1) attribute credit appropriately and (2) re-locate the original source.

> (1) Carver, A.; Gallicchio, V. S. Heavy Metals and Cancer. In Cancer Causing Substances; Atroshi, F., Ed.; 2018. https://doi.org/10.5772/intechopen.68247.

Answer (score -1):

A book is a written work distributed by a publisher, in physical or digital form. (Books and eBooks needn't be distinguished, they contain the same content.) Book drafts are distinguished, they are distributed by authors.